# LocalDateTime with minimum LocalDate and Timezone (ZoneId.SYSTEM)

Tags: js-joda, zoneid

I'm attempting to format a LocalTime object to a formatted string - but due to business requirements I also need to pass a ZoneId to allow for changing the time potentially - then I can format it.

What I have currently is something like this:
`LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.MIN, temporal).atZone(tz).format(formatter.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH))`

Where `temporal` is the LocalTime object being passed - and `tz` being `ZoneId.SYSTEM` and `formatter` being the passed in format (in my case it's `HH:mm`).

What I've noticed is this code won't work and will return an error message in the JavaScript console with the message "Invalid int value, using NaN as argument" - however if I replace `LocalDate.MIN` in the `LocalDateTime.of` function with `LocalDate.Now()` - it will work.

Why is this the case? Is it because `LocalDate.MIN` is too low of a number (being -9999-99...)? Is there a way to have something similar to `LocalDate.MIN` work in this scenario?